Revamping an old underfloor heating system
I live in a house that was built in the late 80s and for the past few years I've been working on making it more efficient.
The underfloor heating system works great, but never had any thermostats nor actuators. As a result, temperature regulation of the individual circuits is entirely manual and approximate.

The boiler always maintains the water at a fixed temperature, as there is nothing toggling the heater on demand.
A Polytherm controller manages both the circulation pump (on/off) and the mixing valve (open/closed, modulated). It monitors the water temperature through a sensor attached to the pipe going up.
An ESP32 relay module was put in place of the analog clock that broke many years ago.



I was considering a DIY solution with (plenty of) relays until I found Homematic, which I promptly liked because they offer a no-cloud solution that keeps working reliably even when if the network is unstable or goes down. I spent several hours on researching what would be needed to revamp the heating system and I came up with the following list:

1 * HmIP-CCU3 (central unit)
1 * HmIP-WHS2 (powers the circulation pump, tells the boiler that heat is needed)
1 * HmIP-FALMOT-C12 (actuators controller)
9 * HmIP-VDMOT (one actuator per heating circuit)
4 * HmIP-WTH-2 (one thermostat per heating zone)

I'm pretty sure the hardware listed above should cover everything except for the mixing valve, which I'm honestly uncertain how I should deal with.
In theory if I set the boiler temperature correctly there should be (almost?) no need for the mixing valve to be actively regulated. Can I just keep it manual, perhaps with a temperature sensor to be used as a high temperature alarm?
I found a few pictures online of the full circulation pump + mixing valve block:




Thanks in advance!

Before you eliminate the mixing valve, shouldn't you monitor the temperature coming out of the boiler before the existing mixing valve during a heating cycle? Surely the temperature fluctuates as the flame cycles on and off. The modulating mixing valve eliminates the wide temp swings in circulating water. What if there is a temperature alarm and no one there to act on it? Will you have a way to ramp up temperature during colder outdoor temperatures? My underfloor heat ramps up by about 10C when outside temps are very cold, which is more efficient than leaving it that hot all the time.

Also, if you are not using a mixing valve and only allow the water to heat up to proper circulating temperature but not higher, the combustion chamber may run so cool that condensation becomes excessive. This could promote rust even if the combustion chamber is stainless steel. Short cycling is not efficient.

Excellent point! The boiler actually shows the temperature and I can confirm the wide temperature swings at the start and end of a heat cycle. I also have a thermal camera I can use to monitor the pipes.
For reference, I have a Vaillant VMW IT 346/5-5 H R4, which is a condensing boiler and also heats domestic water.
Also, I forgot to mention the Polytherm controller makes use of an outdoor temperature sensor (would be replaced by a HmIP-STHO).
Basically, I would need a way to control the mixing valve through Homematic, right? Do you have any suggestions for that?

Alternatively, I could integrate the Polytherm controller into the new system, at least for the time being. It appears to be doing its job just fine.

No suggestions. My mixing valve is electric servo, self contained, no data link, just an outdoor sensor. Taco iSeries.

Thank you, this is helpful! My hardware should work pretty much the same way, it just appears more complicated due to the mixing valve being mechanically driven by the Polytherm controller.
I'll leave an update here as soon as I put together the Homematic system!
